# "Но я думаю, что..." Нужна ли запятая после но?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Но я думаю, что цвет волос по-прежнему выглядит как её оригинальный.

Answer (score 2):

**Но я думаю, что цвет волос по-прежнему выглядит как её оригинальный.**

Или лучше: Но я думаю, что цвет волос по-прежнему выглядит **как её собственный цвет.**

Запятая не нужна, НО ― присоединительный союз.

Вопрос о постановке запятой после присоединительных союзов обычно решается, если после союза **следует какая-нибудь грамматическая конструкция** (придаточное предложение, обособленный оборот, вводное слово), Тогда постановка запятой регулируется правилом Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140

4)  Примечание. Для различных случаев употребления присоединительного союза в самом начале предложения устанавливаются следующие правила...

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Попробуем убрать союз ЧТО, тогда ***я думаю***  будет вводным предложением.  В этом случае после НО желательно поставить запятую, так как сочинительный союз НО не образует с вводным предложением одну фразу, в отличие от вводных слов (требуется интонационное выделение союза).

Розенталь

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

6. Между присоединительным союзом (в начале самостоятельного предложения) и вводным словом (сочетанием) запятая обычно не ставится, так как союз тесно примыкает к вводному слову:  **Но конечно**, всё кончилось благополучно; Н**о так или иначе**, предложенный вариант вполне приемлем;

Иногда (при интонационном выделении вводных слов или предложений...) после присоединительного союза запятая перед вводной конструкцией ставится: **Но, к великой моей досаде,** Швабрин… решительно объявил, что песня моя нехороша (И.); И, как водится, вспоминали только одно хорошее (Крым.).

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы ставите запятую после «но», то таким образом выделяется вводная конструкция «я думаю», а сам союз «но» получается относящимся к остальному предложению. Если мы попробуем опустить такую вводную конструкцию, получится: «Но что цвет волос по-прежнему выглядит как её оригинальный», — в данном контексте получится бессмыслица, разрушится синтаксическая структура. Значит, после «но» запятую поставить не получится.

Ну или можно просто порассуждать, к какой же части относится союз «но». Думаю, очевидно, что по смыслу он относится именно к словам «я думаю».

Comment: А где Вы здесь увидели вводную конструкцию? Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным. Существует вводное предложение "я думаю",  но тогда отсутствует союз ЧТО,

Answer (score 0):

1. Сомневаетесь, выделять ли запятыми "я думаю". Простой рецепт. Уберите эти слова и посмотрите, что получится: **Но что цвет волос по-прежнему выглядит как её оригинальный** (?!). Вывод: не выделяйте.
2. Заимствованное слово *оригинальный* имеет в русском языке несколько значений, в том числе совершено неподходящие для данного случае (своеобразный, необычный, непохожий на других). Стилистически оно здесь не оправдано. Принято писать "свой цвет волос", "свой натуральный цвет волос", "свой естественный цвет волос".
3. Не очень удачно и сочетание "цвет волос выглядит". Выглядят скорее волосы, а не их цвет, а цвет кажется, производит впечатление.
4. Лучше "цвет **ее** волос ... как натуральный", а не "цвет (непонятно чьих) волос .. как **ее** натуральный".

Предлагаю такой вариант: **Но я думаю, что цвет ее волос по-прежнему производит впечатление естественного (ее собственного, натурального).**

Comment: 1)  Собственный цвет волос и натуральный/естественный - это разные вещи. Крашенные в другой цвет волосы могут казаться естественными, но это будет уже не собственный цвет. 2) Чем "производить впечатление" лучше, чем "выглядеть", информативность вроде бы  та же.

Comment: @Jasmin 1) Действительно,  натуральный и естественный могут иметь как смысл  "данный ей прирoдой", так и смысл "существующий в природе", то есть не обязательно ее собственный. Однако в данном контексте нет разницы, так как речь идет о крашеных волосах,  любой их натуральный вид производит впечатление собственного цвета.

Comment: @Jasmin 2) Цвет, как одно из качеств предмета, может  воздействовать на человека (казаться, производить впечатление), но выглядеть — это значит "иметь тот или иной вид", а это это уже относится ка предмету в целом (к волосам). Есть, однако, в словаре и "ВЫГЛЯДЕТЬ - восприниматься каким-л. образом", но, я думаю, это тоже относится к предметам в целом.